# Facing issue While working on incoming TCP network stream

Tags: azure, stream, blob, memorystream

I'm trying to upload files(blob)  to Azure storage  through FTP service by reading the incoming TCP network stream.
Whenever I try to perform operations like stream.length, stream.seek  in the Uploadblob Method, I get following Unhandled exception:

```
 Unhandled Exception!
 Error ID: 0
 Error Code: Unknown
 Is Warning: False
Type: System.NotSupportedException
 Stack:    at     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.get_Length()
```

Workaround would be reading from the stream until it's exhausted, copying the data into a MemoryStream.
Would like to know if somebody got better solution(workaround) rather than copying incoming stream to a memorystream and working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a stream protocol and bytes flow at an arbitrary rate. Also a network stream remains open until it is closed by one end of the stream, this might not give you to exact length at certain point during the call. Mostly you are getting those exceptions due to this reason.

As you mentioned, once you have your own memorystream in which you can dump tcp stream content but still have more control in stream. Once you have a memorystream managed by your, you can upload blob directly from MemoryStream,